# GPIO PWM. ESCs still run different after calibration

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, pwm, pigpio

I’m putting a quadcopter together. I’m using a python script to calibrate the ESCs... they beep like a blinking led when I give them power. Then I run the calibrate script and they give me the proper beep beep ... beeeeeep. To indicate they are ready.

Unfortunately they still give different throttle like I never calibrated them. Any suggestions? I’m using the standard raspberry pi GPIO library. The motors do get power. Here are is my calibration and flight controller as gists.

Calibrate
https://gist.github.com/Hart87/ce05a66deb7fb4a9f387f3c712d3dacf

And then after the proper tone. I run the flight controller to use it
https://gist.github.com/Hart87/a1999b61d8a43fed74cc0df29442771d

Any suggestions? Would a hardware pwm help, like pigpio?

Comment: I read your two python programs and found them straight  forward Rpi.GPIO.  I don't see any problems.  I wonder you have compared other similar software.  I have been playing with PWM using Rpi.GPIO and also PCA9685 (Ref MagPi84 Page 44).  I am using a scope to display the PWM waveform with different duty cycles and found everything easy to debug.  I use PWM to control servos and DC motors, and also BLDC motors, but almost always low current, less than 2A motors.  I have no experience in using ESC RC BLDC motors which I know take big current.  Perhaps there are high noise problems.

Comment: I must confess that though I know quite a bit of Rpi python PWM controlling servos/dc motors, I understand too little quadcopter arming to understanding your problem. I am googling to catch up -  Arming the motors: http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/arming_the_motors.html

Comment: Now I am thinking of getting a quadcopter with GPS, to start my learning experience : 
Top 5 Best Quadcopters with GPS 2019 Reviews - Pierce Lancaster 2019aug20
https://thewiredshopper.com/quadcopters-with-gps/

Comment: You are using very odd values to drive your ESCs.  At 100 Hz a 11% dutycycle results in a pulse width of  1100 µs.  I'd expect to see 2000 µs for the maximum.  A 3% dutycycle results in a 300 µs pulse.  Well below the expected minimum of 1000 µs.  I suggest you use (my) pigpio to properly drive these ESCs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to post this as an answer because I had a lot of trouble researching how to drive an ESC with just a Rasp Pi(using a zero w) and it works now, Hopefully someone having the trouble finding out how will see this:

Joan was completely right with the 1000 low and 2000 ms high pulse width.

I ran the GPIO pins at 50 hz. Here is some light arithmetic that helped ...

1,000,000 / 50hz = 20,000
 a low of 1000ms is 5%  (20,000 / .05)
 a high of 2000ms is 10% (20,000 / .10)

I calibrated the ESCs at 10% duty cycle and then let the low drop to 5%. The result was an arming beep - BEEP BEEP ..... BEEEEEEEP.

Both ESCs ran at the right and same values inputted into my flight controller algorithm.

The motors did run and transition well but a little bit choppy. I'm going to try running it with PIGPIO now to drive it better.

Comment: This is a gist i used to drive ESCs with PIGPIO by Joan. it works PERFECT! Very smooth. Everything in sync. https://gist.github.com/Hart87/e7ddf4a03437ece58c4425b5785b77b4